# Custom actions kicktart commerce cart

Tags: commerce, entities, actions, javascript

Hi I've been struggling with this issue for a while, look for it from google to the official [Drupal Commerce documentation](http://www.drupalcommerce.org) without any luck. So i have a cart and I am customizing the looking and the behaviour, tpl and preprocess function have been my friend until now.

I need to custom the bottom actions of the cart

[image]

But I haven't been able to look for a tpl and I still don't know how to change the behaviour of this actions if you can give a hint of how to:

- Change the value of the  of both of this action
- How to add more actions.
- How to change the behaviour of the items.

BTW. I look for it on the setting of the Views without any luck, but I'm kind of noob in drupal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom module and use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify the form.

That particular form id is `views_form_commerce_cart_form_default`, so in your custom module, you could have something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //cart form
  if (strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default') === 0) {
    //change the value
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "New Update cart value";
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = "New Check-out Value";

    //add additional callback functions on the checkout button
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_callback';

    //replace callback functions on the checkout button
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#submit'] = array('mymodule_callback');
  }
}
```

Refer to the [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to see what else you can do.